# Using \r in bash PS1

Tags: bash, iterm2, ps1, carriage-return

I was getting a little tired of my typeaheads in Bash from messing up the PS1. For instance, I would execute a command, like `ls`, and while it is running, start typing the next command, like `echo`, and the typeahead for `echo` would appear before the PS1, like

```
/$ls
...
ec/$echo
```

(here `/$` is the `PS1`). My solution for this was to add `\r` to the front of the PS1, so that it would clear the line first.

This seems to work reasonably well, but there seems to be a strange issue. In my `.inputrc`, I have

```
"\ep": history-search-backward
```

to let me type `M-p` to go backward (iTerm 2 maps Option to escape correctly).

The issue is that sometimes when I type some stuff and then `M-p` to get the previous command, then I do a `C-u C-k` to clear the line, the first character stays, and becomes part of the `PS1` (it is deleted from the executed line, but it is shown on the PS1). It does away when I execute the command, but whenever I hit that item in the history, even with the regular up arrow, that first character gets stuck there again. This only seems to happen with commands that are of a certain length. It doesn't matter if the `\r` actually clears any text for it to happen.

Am I hitting a strange bug in bash and/or iTerm? Is adding `\r` to the front of `PS1` the correct way to clear cruft before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal to `bash` that the `\r` is a non-printing character so that the correct length of the prompt string is computed, that is, instead of

```
PS1='\rstuff'
```

use

```
PS1='\[\r\]stuff'
```

I think since `\r` is at the beginning of the prompt, it's is always a zero-length character, rather than a variable-length negative-width character as it could be considered if it occurs in the middle of the prompt som where, so this should work.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know bash was doing some prompt length arithmetic.